# JsonSerializationException on lazy loaded nHibernate object in WebApi when called from Angularjs service

Tags: json, angularjs, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a WebApi controller Get method from an Angularjs service.

The angular service:

```
app.service('MyService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var getMyObjects = function () {
        var myObjects;
        var promise = $http.get('/api/objects/').success(function (data) {
            myObjects = data;
         }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

         });

         return promise;
    };

    return {
        myObjects: myObjects
    };
}]);
```

The WebApi Get method:

```
public class ObjectsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> Get()
    {
        return _objectRepository.GetAll().ToArray();
    }
}
```

I am getting a `500 server error` on the client, the inner exception of which is:

```
ExceptionMessage: "Error getting value from 'IdentityEqualityComparer' on 
'NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultLazyInitializer'."
ExceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

**EDIT:** 
I resolved the above exception by adding the following one liner to `WebApiConfig.cs` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278092/1005609):

```
((DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.
                           ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
```

Now I have this exception:

```
ExceptionMessage: "Error getting value from 'DefaultValue'
on 'NHibernate.Type.DateTimeOffsetType'."
ExceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"
```

Any ideas on if there is something similar I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926718/1005609) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274791/1005609), I have fixed the issue by adding the following class

```
public class NHibernateContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
   protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType) 
   {
      if (typeof(NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
          return base.CreateContract(objectType.BaseType);

        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}
```

and then setting it as the contract resolver in `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
                            .ContractResolver = new NHibernateContractResolver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading is worth having whole DB crash. Lazy load prevents you from loading unnecessary referenced data. But also you must ensure that you have pointed [hibernate which references to load.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410591/nhibernate-lazy-loading-behaviour)

But your exception is thrown because of **[Serialization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053109/failed-to-serialize-the-response-body-for-content-type)**